# unable to get the expected output,i should get true but when executed i am getting false?

Tags: java, string

when i run the HelloWorld java code,i am getting false instead of getting true,don't know where i did wrong? thanks ...

```
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String []args){
boolean b=mixStart("kixten");
System.out.println(b);
}
public static boolean mixStart(String str) {
String a="ix";
if(str.substring(1,3)==a){
System.out.println("true");
return true;
}
else{  
System.out.println("false");
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Option (a) use equals "str.substring(1,3).equals(a)" rather than '==', or                   Option(b) "str.substring(1,3).intern() == a"

Comment: I think you should read the diffrence between == and equals here 
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

Comment: Please re-edit with proper code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*you just need to change you code likewise,*

```
if(str.substring(1,3).equals(a)){...}
```

**what you did wrong is ,**

> you have been used '==' assignment operator,
>
> it is not comparing content(here, string) instead of it, it compare's
>   memory location between two compared string.
>
> it's obvious to get false, because how is it possible ? that two
>   different string refer to same memory-location.
>
> so this is all about '==' relational-operator does.
>
> if you use 'equals(..)' then it is compares string unlike
>   memory-location(==).

Answer (score 0):

You should use.

```
str.substring(1,3).matches(a)
```

instead of

`str.substring(1,3) == a`

Like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean b = mixStart("kixten");
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static boolean mixStart(String str) {
    String a = "ix";
    if (str.substring(1, 3).matches(a)) {
        System.out.println("true");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
        return false;
    }
}
```